# Error in building angular code source to contribute

Tags: angular, build

I want to build the angular code source. I follow the [guide line](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/angular/cli/README.md#development-hints-for-working-on-angular-cli) , but I get error when I run `node ./scripts/build/build-packages-dist.js`

This is the output

```
node ./scripts/build/build-packages-dist.js
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
C:/users/khalid-info/_bazel_khalid-info/vo53ftom/execroot/angular/bazel-out/x64_windows-fastbuild/bin
##################################
scripts\build\build-packages-dist.js:
  Building @angular/* npm packages
  Mode: Production
##################################
Loading: 293 packages loaded
//packages/upgrade:npm_package
//packages/service-worker:npm_package
//packages/router:npm_package
//packages/platform-server:npm_package
//packages/platform-browser-dynamic:npm_package
//packages/platform-browser:npm_package
//packages/localize:npm_package
//packages/language-service:npm_package
//packages/forms:npm_package
//packages/elements:npm_package
//packages/core:npm_package
//packages/compiler-cli:npm_package
//packages/compiler:npm_package
//packages/common:npm_package
//packages/bazel:npm_package
//packages/animations:npm_package
INFO: Analyzed 16 targets (272 packages loaded, 22332 targets configured).
INFO: Found 16 targets...
ERROR: D:/angular/packages/localize/src/localize/BUILD.bazel:5:11: Compiling TypeScript (devmode) //packages/localize/src/localize:localize failed: Worker process quit or closed its stdin stream when we tried to send a WorkRequest:

---8<---8<--- Exception details ---8<---8<---
java.io.IOException: ERROR: src/main/native/windows/processes-jni.cc(356): NativeProcess:WriteStdin(2076): The pipe is being closed.

        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.windows.WindowsSubprocess.writeStream(WindowsSubprocess.java:270)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.windows.WindowsSubprocess.access$000(WindowsSubprocess.java:32)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.windows.WindowsSubprocess$ProcessOutputStream.write(WindowsSubprocess.java:56)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutputStreamEncoder.doFlush(CodedOutputStream.java:3062)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutputStreamEncoder.write(CodedOutputStream.java:2994)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutputStreamEncoder.writeLazy(CodedOutputStream.java:3013)
        at com.google.protobuf.ByteString$LiteralByteString.writeTo(ByteString.java:1392)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutputStreamEncoder.writeBytesNoTag(CodedOutputStream.java:2801)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutputStreamEncoder.writeBytes(CodedOutputStream.java:2775)
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.writeString(GeneratedMessageV3.java:3092)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.worker.WorkerProtocol$Input.writeTo(WorkerProtocol.java:235)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutputStreamEncoder.writeMessageNoTag(CodedOutputStream.java:2855)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutputStreamEncoder.writeMessage(CodedOutputStream.java:2824)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.worker.WorkerProtocol$WorkRequest.writeTo(WorkerProtocol.java:1091)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite.writeDelimitedTo(AbstractMessageLite.java:95)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.worker.ProtoWorkerProtocol.putRequest(ProtoWorkerProtocol.java:38)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.worker.SingleplexWorker.putRequest(SingleplexWorker.java:117)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.worker.WorkerSpawnRunner.execInWorker(WorkerSpawnRunner.java:453)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.worker.WorkerSpawnRunner.actuallyExec(WorkerSpawnRunner.java:227)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.worker.WorkerSpawnRunner.exec(WorkerSpawnRunner.java:144)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.exec.SpawnRunner.execAsync(SpawnRunner.java:240)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.exec.AbstractSpawnStrategy.exec(AbstractSpawnStrategy.java:140)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.exec.AbstractSpawnStrategy.exec(AbstractSpawnStrategy.java:102)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.actions.SpawnStrategy.beginExecution(SpawnStrategy.java:47)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.exec.SpawnStrategyResolver.beginExecution(SpawnStrategyResolver.java:65)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.analysis.actions.SpawnAction.beginExecution(SpawnAction.java:331)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.actions.Action.execute(Action.java:127)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SkyframeActionExecutor$5.execute(SkyframeActionExecutor.java:855)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SkyframeActionExecutor$ActionRunner.continueAction(SkyframeActionExecutor.java:1016)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SkyframeActionExecutor$ActionRunner.run(SkyframeActionExecutor.java:975)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.ActionExecutionState.runStateMachine(ActionExecutionState.java:129)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.ActionExecutionState.getResultOrDependOnFuture(ActionExecutionState.java:81)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SkyframeActionExecutor.executeAction(SkyframeActionExecutor.java:472)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.ActionExecutionFunction.checkCacheAndExecuteIfNeeded(ActionExecutionFunction.java:834)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.ActionExecutionFunction.compute(ActionExecutionFunction.java:307)
        at com.google.devtools.build.skyframe.AbstractParallelEvaluator$Evaluate.run(AbstractParallelEvaluator.java:477)        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.concurrent.AbstractQueueVisitor$WrappedRunnable.run(AbstractQueueVisitor.java:398)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
---8<---8<--- End of exception details ---8<---8<---

---8<---8<--- Start of log, file at C:/users/khalid-info/_bazel_khalid-info/vo53ftom/bazel-workers/worker-2-TypeScriptCompile.log ---8<---8<---
'""' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
---8<---8<--- End of log ---8<---8<---
ERROR: D:/angular/packages/platform-browser/BUILD.bazel:5:10 Bundling DTS (devmode) //packages/platform-browser:platform-browser failed: Worker process quit or closed its stdin stream when we tried to send a WorkRequest:

---8<---8<--- Exception details ---8<---8<---
java.io.IOException: ERROR: src/main/native/windows/processes-jni.cc(356): NativeProcess:WriteStdin(2076): The pipe is being closed.

        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.windows.WindowsSubprocess.writeStream(WindowsSubprocess.java:270)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.windows.WindowsSubprocess.access$000(WindowsSubprocess.java:32)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.windows.WindowsSubprocess$ProcessOutputStream.write(WindowsSubprocess.java:56)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutputStreamEncoder.doFlush(CodedOutputStream.java:3062)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutputStreamEncoder.write(CodedOutputStream.java:2994)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutputStreamEncoder.writeLazy(CodedOutputStream.java:3013)
        at com.google.protobuf.ByteString$LiteralByteString.writeTo(ByteString.java:1392)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutputStreamEncoder.writeBytesNoTag(CodedOutputStream.java:2801)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutputStreamEncoder.writeBytes(CodedOutputStream.java:2775)
        at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageV3.writeString(GeneratedMessageV3.java:3092)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.worker.WorkerProtocol$Input.writeTo(WorkerProtocol.java:235)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutputStreamEncoder.writeMessageNoTag(CodedOutputStream.java:2855)
        at com.google.protobuf.CodedOutputStream$OutputStreamEncoder.writeMessage(CodedOutputStream.java:2824)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.worker.WorkerProtocol$WorkRequest.writeTo(WorkerProtocol.java:1091)
        at com.google.protobuf.AbstractMessageLite.writeDelimitedTo(AbstractMessageLite.java:95)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.worker.ProtoWorkerProtocol.putRequest(ProtoWorkerProtocol.java:38)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.worker.SingleplexWorker.putRequest(SingleplexWorker.java:117)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.worker.WorkerSpawnRunner.execInWorker(WorkerSpawnRunner.java:453)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.worker.WorkerSpawnRunner.actuallyExec(WorkerSpawnRunner.java:227)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.worker.WorkerSpawnRunner.exec(WorkerSpawnRunner.java:144)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.exec.SpawnRunner.execAsync(SpawnRunner.java:240)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.exec.AbstractSpawnStrategy.exec(AbstractSpawnStrategy.java:140)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.exec.AbstractSpawnStrategy.exec(AbstractSpawnStrategy.java:102)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.actions.SpawnStrategy.beginExecution(SpawnStrategy.java:47)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.exec.SpawnStrategyResolver.beginExecution(SpawnStrategyResolver.java:65)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.analysis.actions.SpawnAction.beginExecution(SpawnAction.java:331)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.actions.Action.execute(Action.java:127)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SkyframeActionExecutor$5.execute(SkyframeActionExecutor.java:855)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SkyframeActionExecutor$ActionRunner.continueAction(SkyframeActionExecutor.java:1016)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SkyframeActionExecutor$ActionRunner.run(SkyframeActionExecutor.java:975)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.ActionExecutionState.runStateMachine(ActionExecutionState.java:129)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.ActionExecutionState.getResultOrDependOnFuture(ActionExecutionState.java:81)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.SkyframeActionExecutor.executeAction(SkyframeActionExecutor.java:472)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.ActionExecutionFunction.checkCacheAndExecuteIfNeeded(ActionExecutionFunction.java:834)
        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.skyframe.ActionExecutionFunction.compute(ActionExecutionFunction.java:307)
        at com.google.devtools.build.skyframe.AbstractParallelEvaluator$Evaluate.run(AbstractParallelEvaluator.java:477)        at com.google.devtools.build.lib.concurrent.AbstractQueueVisitor$WrappedRunnable.run(AbstractQueueVisitor.java:398)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
---8<---8<--- End of exception details ---8<---8<---

---8<---8<--- Start of log, file at C:/users/khalid-info/_bazel_khalid-info/vo53ftom/bazel-workers/worker-2-TypeScriptCompile.log ---8<---8<---
'""' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
---8<---8<--- End of log ---8<---8<---
INFO: Elapsed time: 24.112s, Critical Path: 6.79s
INFO: 15 processes: 15 internal.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
child_process.js:836
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Command failed: yarn --cwd "D:\angular" --silent bazel build --config=snapshot --config=view-engine //packages/upgrade:npm_package //packages/service-worker:npm_package //packages/router:npm_package //packages/platform-server:npm_package //packages/platform-browser-dynamic:npm_package //packages/platform-browser:npm_package //packages/localize:npm_package //packages/language-service:npm_package //packages/forms:npm_package //packages/elements:npm_package //packages/core:npm_package //packages/compiler-cli:npm_package //packages/compiler:npm_package //packages/common:npm_package //packages/bazel:npm_package //packages/animations:npm_package
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:760:11)
    at execSync (child_process.js:833:15)
    at exec (D:\angular\scripts\build\package-builder.js:142:18)
    at buildTargetPackages (D:\angular\scripts\build\package-builder.js:96:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\angular\scripts\build\build-packages-dist.js:18:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12) {
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, null, null ],
  pid: 3592,
  stdout: null,
  stderr: null
}
```

I cant figure out the problem. What I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just experienced this issue, it happens if you attempt to run the command in cmd or powershell.

You need to use bash instead.